# Correctly storing/exposing List of Func<T, TResult> in a class

Tags: c#, class, delegates, lambda

I have a class which needs to provide a way to register an arbitrary number of `Func<T, TResult>` delegates.

These are then later invoked in my class during a series of operations.

What is the correct way to expose the ability to register these delegates? Is it just a public property of `IEnumerable<Func<T, TResult>>`, `IList<Func<T, TResult>>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<Func<T, TResult>>`?

Is there some specific pattern that is typically used here?

To be more specific..

Assume a scenario

```
public class Foo 
{
    public List<Func<Control, Func<bool>>> Conditions { get; set; }
    public void DoWork() 
    {
         foreach (Func<Control, Func<bool>> condition in this.Conditions)
             var result = condition.Invoke(new Control());
    }

}
```

Is this an acceptable implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information. It will depend completely on your situation, particularly on the contractual guarantees you want to provide (e.g. guaranteed order, immutability of the collection, etc.). Unless you have special requirements, I suggest you just go with the simplest version -- `IEnumerable<Func<T, TResult>>` -- and leave the rest to your implementation. That's what I've done in the past.

As for using a `List` as in your example, there's nothing intrinsically wrong with that. You may find it convenient to stick with `IEnumerable<Func<T, TResult>>` so as not to restrict yourself more than necessary. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can still use `Conditions = new List<Func<T, TResult>>` when you initialize it.